# How to convert system time to 64 bit file time structure of NTFS in DOS

Tags: c, dos, ntfs

I am using DJGPP compiler for DOS in that i have to use WINDOWS.h which is a win32 api for conversion of system time to file time for NTFS file system.As windows.h is win32 api it is giving error "windows.h-no such file or directory".So how to convert system time to file time (i.e.8 byte structure) in NTFS file system for NTFS file system in DOS.

Comment: Does DOS even support NTFS? I don't think so. Why aren't you using Windows compiler to write Windows programs?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft's FILETIME is multiples of 100ns since January 1, 1601 and a 64 bit unsigned variable.

In NTFS these are stored ad little-endian. You can convert the date yourself:

(uint64)UnixTime * 10000000 + 12219292800000000ui64
uint64 is your 64 bit unsigned type
and the ui64 suffix telles the compile the constant is 
a 64 bit unsigned